# Proper way to set up reference to System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

My solution contains several projects. One of them (DataBaseProject) is using Sqlite so I've added reference to System.Data.Sqlite and set "copy local" to TRUE. DataBaseProject is referenced by MainProject. After build in MainProject bin folder there is only DataBaseProject.dll but missing System.Data.Sqlite.dll. How to set up project, that System.Data.Sqlite.dll would be in bin folder of MainProject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the reference also to MainProject or, as you say, copied into its bin folder.

Comment: I thought that I don't have to add another reference of Sqlite to MainProject if only I have that reference in DataBaseProject.

Comment: @torpederos Unfortunately Main project doesn't have a way to know about your output dependency. If that library were just for compile, then no problem. But, as you actually need it to execute your app, then Main project needs to know that by, precisely, referencing.